# Jquery scroll fixo no top ao clicar em uma div #

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Galera seguinte estou com um problema pois quando eu clicava em um menu ancorado por uma #id ele nao ficava com o scroll no topo e assim o conteudo era cortado pois agora eu coloquei está função e funcionou perfeitamente porém quando vou olhar no console da erro

Jquery:

```
 $('.sub-menu a').click(function() {

    var anchor;
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
        anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
    }

    $('.id-sub').slideUp(2000);
     if (anchor !== undefined) {
        $(anchor).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');
        $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(anchor) }, function(){
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
     }

});
```

este é o erro :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined
at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (scripts.js?ver=4.9.7:30)
at HTMLBodyElement.d.complete (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
at n.fx.tick (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
```

porem eu ja tentei tirar está linha :

```
     function(){
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
```

já tentei criar uma var como null e nada funciona o erro ate sai com essas solucoes acima porem o scroll nao fica fixo no topo poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery vc está usando?

Comment: versão é está 1.12.4

Comment: @FilipeNickelSala pelo que eu entendi `target` é a o nome da âncora que você quer que vá fonte:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: Não sei se pode ser isso, mas as vezes vale a penas testar uma versão mais nova, pois o jQuery já está na versão 3.3.1 se não me engano. Essa versão sua é muito antiga... Tb não sei se é correto não devlarar o valor da variável, mesmo que nula ou indefinida ` var anchor;`

Comment: estou utilizando wordpress será que tem algum problema? eu ja coloquei no lugar do target o anchor porém continua mesmo erro

Comment: Testa com uma versão mais nova só pra ver se resolver... https://code.jquery.com/ clica em uncompressed e pega o link do CDN 3.x e testa

Comment: beleza vou testar ja te falo valeu

Comment: <!--$('.sub-menu a').click(function() {
        
        var anchor;
        var link = $(this).attr('href');

        var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
        

        if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
        }
        
        $('.id-sub').slideUp(2000);
         if (anchor !== undefined) {
            $(anchor).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');
             $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(anchor) }, 600, function(){
       window.location.hash = target;
    });
         }
     
    });-->

Comment: fiz igual a cima mais nao funcionou e ja atualizei jquery para nova versão

Comment: atualizei Jquery agora nem sem o target funciona mais  kkk so quero que o scroll fique fixado no topo quando é chamada a (anchor)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Efeito SliderDown/SliderUp
$('.sub-menu a').click(function() {

    var anchor;
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
        anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
        console.log('anchor',anchor);
    }

    $('.id-sub').slideUp(2000);
    if (anchor !== undefined) {
        $(anchor).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');       
        $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(anchor) }, 600, function(){
            window.location.hash = target;
        })
    }
});
```